# Pass array in Intent using parcelable

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, parcelable, extra

I would like to send an array of objects between activities. I want to use the parcelable interface and send the data in an intent. However I keep getting errors. I have been stuck for 2 days. Here are some details about my problem.

**Class A**

```
private ProjetUI[] mProjects;

private final View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProjetListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(ProjetListActivity.ARG_PROJECTS, mProjects);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

**Class B**

```
ProjetUI[] mProjects = getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra(ARG_PROJECTS);
```

I get a compilation error "Incompatible types"
After casting to (ProjetUI[]), I get a runtime error "Cannot cast Parcelable[] to ProjetUI[]"

**Class Projet**

```
public class ProjetUI implements Parcelable {

private String id;
private String idParent;
private String nom;
private String description;
private List<ProjetColonneUI> colonnes;
private List<VueUI> vues;
private boolean archive;
private String version;
private String commentaire;
private boolean published;
private List<DroitAccesUI> droitAcces;
private String idDossier;
private String typeDossier;
private String idModele;
private List<ProjetDatasetUI> projetDatasets;

protected ProjetUI(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readString();
    idParent = in.readString();
    nom = in.readString();
    description = in.readString();
    colonnes = in.createTypedArrayList(ProjetColonneUI.CREATOR);
    vues = in.createTypedArrayList(VueUI.CREATOR);
    archive = in.readInt() == 1;
    version = in.readString();
    commentaire = in.readString();
    published = in.readInt() == 1;
    droitAcces = in.createTypedArrayList(DroitAccesUI.CREATOR);
    idDossier = in.readString();
    typeDossier = in.readString();
    idModele = in.readString();
    projetDatasets = in.createTypedArrayList(ProjetDatasetUI.CREATOR);
}

public static final Creator<ProjetUI> CREATOR = new Creator<ProjetUI>() {
    @Override
    public ProjetUI createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ProjetUI(in);
    }

    @Override
    public ProjetUI[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ProjetUI[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
    parcel.writeString(getId());
    parcel.writeString(getIdParent());
    parcel.writeString(getNom());
    parcel.writeString(getDescription());
    parcel.writeTypedList(getColonnes());
    parcel.writeTypedList(getVues());
    parcel.writeInt(isArchive() ? 1 : 0);
    parcel.writeString(getVersion());
    parcel.writeString(getCommentaire());
    parcel.writeInt(isPublished() ? 1 : 0);
    parcel.writeTypedList(getDroitAcces());
    parcel.writeString(getIdDossier());
    parcel.writeString(getTypeDossier());
    parcel.writeString(getIdModele());
    parcel.writeTypedList(getProjetDatasets());
}
}
```

**EDIT**

[This is the complete stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlC7G.png)

The other classes implement parcelable just like ProjeUI class.
Here is an example of another class that has an enum type and an example of an enum that implements parcelable

```
public class VueRelationUI implements Parcelable {

private String id;
private String idVue;
private String idRelation;
private RelationType typeRelation;

protected VueRelationUI(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readString();
    idVue = in.readString();
    idRelation = in.readString();
    typeRelation = in.readParcelable(RelationType.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Creator<VueRelationUI> CREATOR = new Creator<VueRelationUI>() {
    @Override
    public VueRelationUI createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new VueRelationUI(in);
    }

    @Override
    public VueRelationUI[] newArray(int size) {
        return new VueRelationUI[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
    parcel.writeString(getId());
    parcel.writeString(getIdVue());
    parcel.writeString(getIdRelation());
    parcel.writeParcelable(getTypeRelation(), flags);
}
}
```

**ENUM**

```
public enum RelationType implements Parcelable {

INNER,
OUTER;

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
    parcel.writeInt(ordinal());
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public static final Creator<RelationType> CREATOR = new Creator<RelationType>() {
    @Override
    public RelationType createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
        return RelationType.values()[parcel.readInt()];
    }

    @Override
    public RelationType[] newArray(int size) {
        return new RelationType[size];
    }
};
}
```

*Any help would be much appreciated*

Comment: Please share the complete stacktrace?  and does the other classes implement parcelable correctly?

Comment: I recommend Parceler.  It makes this stuff much simpler.  https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler

Comment: I will check it out. However, I would rather understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: add the code of projectuiactivity also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem happens because of the internal implementation of Android's `Parcel` class. When you start the new activity, all of the intent extras are parceled and then unparceled. When this happens, the Android framework allocates a new `Parcelable[]`, and **not** a new `ProjetUI[]`. So you get a `ClassCastException` when you try to cast it.

Probably the best solution would be to change your code to use `ArrayList<ProjetUI>` instead of `ProjetUI[]`. Then you can use `Intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra()` and `getParcelableArrayListExtra()` without any problems.

If you can't do that for some reason, then you will have to manually cast the array one element at a time:

```
Parcelable[] parcelables = getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra(ARG_PROJECTS);
ProjetUI[] mProjects = new ProjetUI[parcelables.length];

for (int i = 0; i < parcelables.length; ++i) {
    mProjects[i] = (ProjetUI) parcelables[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the manual approach worked. I will look into changing my code to ArrayList

Comment: Which part of the Parcel class please? `MyObject[] objects = getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra(ARG_MY_OBJECTS);` works perfectly find on my test devices but crashes showing on Crashlytics

Comment: Do you think you could help with my question @BenP?  :pray: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69817116/java-lang-classcastexception-android-os-parcelable-cannot-be-cast-to-photo