# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.Parcelable[] cannot be cast to Photo[]

Tags: java, android

It's happening for 0.08% of our users.
One of the crashes happening on Samsung Galaxy S10 running Android 11
[image]

It's not crashing on my Samsung Galaxy S10 running Android 11 though!

Does anyone know why?
Line where it crashes

```java
Photo[] photoArray = (Photo[]) bundle.getParcelableArray(EXTRA_PHOTOS);
```

**1st finding**

```java
Photo photo1 = new Photo(231, "url", "photoid", "profilid", "caption");
      Parcelable[] parcelables1 = new Parcelable[]{photo1};
      Photo[] array = (Photo[]) parcelables1;
```

Throws `ClassCastException`
This couple with the fact that `Bundle#getParcelableArray` only returns a Parcelable array, not the the concrete class Photo array explains why the crash is expected
But why is it only happening for some users only?

**2nd finding**

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51714927/pass-array-in-intent-using-parcelable) claims that `getParcelableArray()` won't work, only `getParcelableArrayListExtra()` or individual casting will work but the why is unclear to me

**3rd finding**

So I've learnt that downcasting arrays is not supposed to work in Java or Kotlin, at least not in the way Android Bundle do it.
The reason why `getParcelableArrayListExtra()` works is because it assume generic type and did work to handle the type.

Question remains: how come `getParcelableArray()` works nicely in my real device and emulator? Is there some black magic hidden in plain sight here?

Code below

---

Photo.java

```java
public class Photo implements Serializable, Model, Parcelable {

  private String caption;
  private String id, idProfile;
  private int position;
  private String iphoneFullscreen;
  
  public Photo(int position, String url, String photoId, String profileId, String caption) {
    iphoneFullscreen = url;
    this.position = position;
    this.id = photoId;
    idProfile = profileId;
    this.caption = caption;
  }
  
  @Override
  public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.caption);
    dest.writeString(this.id);
    dest.writeString(this.idProfile);
    dest.writeInt(this.position);
    dest.writeString(this.iphoneFullscreen);
  }

  protected Photo(Parcel in) {
    this.caption = in.readString();
    this.id = in.readString();
    this.idProfile = in.readString();
    this.position = in.readInt();
    this.iphoneFullscreen = in.readString();
  }

  public static final Parcelable.Creator<Photo> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Photo>() {
    @Override
    public Photo createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
      return new Photo(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Photo[] newArray(int size) {
      return new Photo[size];
    }
  };
}
```

How it's provided and consumed
DialogFragmentPhotoGallery.java

```java
public static DialogFragment newInstance(
      Photo[] photos) {
    DialogFragmentPhotoGallery dialogFragmentPhotoGallery = new DialogFragmentPhotoGallery();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelableArray(DialogFragmentPhotoGallery.EXTRA_PHOTOS, photos);
    dialogFragmentPhotoGallery.setArguments(args);
    return dialogFragmentPhotoGallery;
  }

 public View onCreateView(
      @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup parent,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (getArguments() != null) {
      Photo[] photos = (Photo[]) getArguments().getParcelableArray(EXTRA_PHOTOS); // <-- CRASH
      // do things with photos
    }
```

Comment: (If you're going to mask out the package name in the screenshot, mask them all out! Second line. But then again, you've got the company name in your profile, so...)